# pdo_oci make does not work

Tags: php, pdo, opensuse, oracle-call-interface

Recently I updated my opensuse 12.3 to the newer 13.1

Unfortunately, I'm not able to compile the pdo_oci.so needed.
Using this guide, y could compile the extnention on 12.3:

http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/418966-installing-pdo_oci-php.html

But unfortunately on the actual version i'm struggling to find a solution.
At the moment i'm trying to execute the make, but y get the following error:

```
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:34:1: error: unknown type name 'function_entry'
 function_entry pdo_oci_functions[] = {
 ^
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
  {NULL, NULL, NULL}
  ^
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: (near initialization for 'pdo_oci_functions[0]') [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: (near initialization for 'pdo_oci_functions[0]') [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: (near initialization for 'pdo_oci_functions[0]') [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:35:2: warning: (near initialization for 'pdo_oci_functions[0]') [enabled by default]
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:56:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  pdo_oci_functions,
  ^
/home/temp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:56:2: warning: (near initialization for 'pdo_oci_module_entry.functions') [enabled by default]
```

make: *** [pdo_oci.lo] Error 1

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Found a solution
I'm not quite sure why but it work's

Replace function_entry with zend_function_entry in pdo_oci.c at line 36

Answer (score 7):

hefengxian he 's solution worked for me but I can't make comments yet so here's what I did.

Edit the file pdo_oci.c, around line 34 search for :

```
/* {{{ pdo_oci_functions[] */
function_entry pdo_oci_functions[] = {
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
/* }}} */
```

replace with

```
/* {{{ pdo_oci_functions[] */
zend_function_entry pdo_oci_functions[] = {
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
/* }}} */
```

run make again.

Comment: Your suggestion made `make` and `make install` to continue. But it gives loading error, `pdo_oci.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_stmt_delref in Unknown on line 0` (My environment: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit; Oracle Instant Client 12.1.0.2.0; PDO_OCI 1.0)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the solution for this. It worked for me, but I ended up installing the extension more easily with the command "pecl install pdo_oci".

Comment: Loading generic pdo, and then loading pdo_oci solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

just change the function 'function_entry' name to 'zend_function_entry' in pdo_oci.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on your answer

Comment: he's telling you how to get rid of "error: unknown type name 'function_entry'"

Comment: fixed related issue with this answer .

Answer (score 0):

It means that 'pdo_oci.lo' is missing when it's compiling. The easy solution is to copy the oci lib from your Oracle-Instant-Client lib to compiled path like this:

```
cp -f /usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64/* include/
```

I hope it can help you!

you can find more detail with follow link:
http://www.indiangnu.org/2010/how-to-install-pdo_oci-extension-for-php-5/